# Creating teams with exactly two men and one woman, where the order matters.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that there are $5$ men and $4$ women. How many ways are there to make a group of three members? Well then
$${9 \choose 3}$$

Now, let's say that now you're making *teams*, and the order does matter, because there are different roles. In this case, we'd use permutations:

$$\frac{9!}{(9 - 3)!}$$

Cool. But now, another constraint: what if the team must have exactly two men and one woman?

If the order didn't matter, I'd just say

$${5\choose2}\cdot4$$

I think. But since the order does matter, I should use permutations, but how? I tried

$$\frac{5!}{(5 - 2)!}\cdot4$$

But I doubt it, because the woman is not being permutated. Then something like

$$\frac{5!}{(5 - 2)!}\cdot \frac{4!}{(4-1)!}$$

Would that do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never been too great at combinatorics, but my first impression it is

$$\binom{5}{2} \binom{4}{1} 3!.$$

You must choose two men and one woman. Then, you must take into account permutations.

Hopefully someone more astute can verify this (or shoot it down).

Comment: This is correct. You choose the required team members, then calculate the number of ways you can order them to fill the three team roles (since the roles are presumably not gender-specific, you don't have to separate male and female at this stage).

Comment: $\checkmark$ That is correct.  You choose 2 of the 5 men, choose 1 of the 4 women, and then assign the selected three to roles.  Count the ways to do each step, and multiply them together.