# Creating groups with 10 men and 10 women.

Tags: combinatorics

I once made a question here: [Creating teams with exactly two men and one woman, where the order matters.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/817609/5775), and the answer worked just fine, although I was still a bit confused. Here is an exercise that I find fairly similar, and in the last question I applied the same formula they did. Is it right?

Have $10$ men and $10$ women.

> How many ways are there to form $5$ groups, where each group must have
>   exactly $2$ men and $2$ women? The five groups are different.

$$\prod_{i = 0}^{4}\left({10 - 2i \choose 2}\cdot{10 - 2i \choose 2}\right)$$

> How many ways are there to make a team with $4$ members, where the
>   order matters?

$$\frac{20!}{(20 - 4)!}$$

> What if in such team there must be at least one woman?

$${10 \choose 1}{19\choose3}4!$$

I did this last question based on this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/817612/5775. You pick one of the $10$ women, then $3$ of the $19$ people left, and then permutate the $4$ roles. Is this right?

Comment: About the second one, if the order matters, why not just answer $20*19*18*17$?

Comment: @DanielY: Well, yeah, no reason in particular. I just used the permutations formula. I think it's the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, if you reduce your fraction, it comes out as the same

Comment: about the others, it seems correct

Comment: Do you have any question regarding my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question: $5!(\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2})^2=5!\binom{10}{2,2,2,2,2}^2$

for the second question: seems legit, $\frac{20!}{(20-4)!}$

for the third question: also seems legit, another answer would be $\frac{20!}{(20-4)!}-\frac{10!}{(10-4)!}$

Comment: Thank you, I think the formula in the first one confuses me. What is the logic behind it exactly? (Yeah I just used the same formula in the third question without knowing why)

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake, yours was right, only you forgot to multiply by 5!, because you need to see in how many ways you can assign each pair of boys to each pair of girls, the second part is just a [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients), but that isn0t really required

Answer (score 2):

for first first you can pick 2 man and 2 women from 10 men and 10 women then you have 4 people and place them in of the 5 places and so on. so you should multiply your answer to $5!$ because it just pick groups and there are no difference between 2 group.

for the second one you should just ${20 \choose 4}$ and multiply it with $4!$ because order of 4 people are important to us. so the answer is correct.

and the last one is correct you pick a woman first and pick 3 other people then multiply it with $4!$ because the order is matter to us.